# When can an asyncio Coroutine be interrupted?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

THe question is quite simple. I am new to python's `asyncio` module and coroutines. If I write an async function like

```
import asyncio

async def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2

    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    return a + b
```

Can this coroutine for example be interrupted after the `a = 1` and before the `b = 2` statement? In actual multithreading of course everything would be asynchronous but as I understand it that is not the case here. So at what statements might a coroutine be interrupted so that the execution returns to the loop? This is for example important when working with locks.

Comment: No. Coroutines are only "interrupted" at `await` points, that's their appeal.

Comment: Remember that asyncio runs things *concurrently* but not *in parallel*. When as async coroutine is running, *nothing else is running* until the routine calls `await`, which returns control to the scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what is in the comments:
async code in Python is only interrupted when there is an `await` instruction, or an `async for ...` or `async with ...` statement.

In your particular example, it will not stop between the `a = 1` and `b = 2` lines. This is the one of the biggest advantages of async programming vs, say, threading: code is deterministic and linear, with the "pause" points explicitly delimited.

Actually, I've found out the problem is often the converse: it is not *always* that an `await` statement shows that the async loop will do a full iteration and give a chance to all running tasks.

What happens is that ultimately, the "leaf" calls of an asyncio tasks, usually the ones that will actually perform I/O and will have to "wait for an external response" are based in callbacks: they schedule a callback which the asyncio loop is aware of, and the `await` interface can be used on top of that. And more than one library presenting itself as "async capable" just *fake* the async part - the inner call, despite being defined with `async def` is just a normal, sync function. Maybe not in all circumstances, sometimes it is just really async when data is not yet ready to fetch on whatever device it is getting it. For example, a call to read data from a file might be "real" async to read a huge amount of data, but just read data and return synchronously when there is not much to do.

So, it happens that when there are calls like these, *even* when there is an await statement in the code, the other tasks don't have a chance to run.

To ensure the asyncio loop runs, the remedy is them inserting an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` (yes, zero): that will have the necessary underlying callback interface which ensures the loop will be able to poll everything there is to poll, and execute a step in all paused code that is ready do proceed (there is no such thing as a priority either: every ready task is called in order).

Anyway, going back to the main subject: in practice, locks are much less necessary in asyncio code (I never needed them so far).

Comment: Do cancellations (raising `CancelledError`) also only occur on these points?

Comment: Yes. They happen as if the `await` statement raised the error (so, it is possible to put `awaits` in a try-except block , and handle "CancelledError"  to act on cancelations.